# QTableWidget setText returning Attribute error

Tags: python, pyside2, qtablewidget

My issue is similar to [PyQt - setText method of QTableWidget gets AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140739/pyqt-settext-method-of-qtablewidget-gets-attributeerror). However, in this case the solution doesn't work.

I'm attempting to rewrite some fields automatically in which the values to be set are held in an array.
As I have some empty rows I iterate over the rows to ensure that the name is relevant to the value that will be set.

```
    #statsPlayer is a class that holds the array through a getter method
    #modelTable is the QTableWidget
    #possibilities is the array that holds the names of the rows that are to be modified

    possiblities = ['Tackles', 'Blocks', 'Interceptions', 'Passes', 'Succesful Dribbles', 'Fouls Drawn', 'Goals', 'Assists', 'Penalties Scored']

    counterTracker = 0
    statsGroup = statsPlayer.statsGetter()[0]


    for row in range(modelTable.rowCount()):


        if modelTable.verticalHeaderItem(row).text() in possiblities:

            modelTable.item(row, 0).setText(str(statsGroup[counterTracker]))
            counterTracker += 1
```

My issue is after the first 3 rows (Tackles, Blocks and Interceptions), I receive an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

The fields that I am attempting to modify are empty, so naturally they will be None. But why is it that I can edit the first 3 values but not the rest?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in a QTableWidget are always `None` until any data (or QTableWidgetItem) is set for them.

Just add a check to ensure that the item exists, and if it doesn't, create it and set it for the table:

```
    item = modelTable.item(row, 0)
    if not item:
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        modelTable.setItem(row, 0, item)
    item.setText(str(statsGroup[counterTracker]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try this in the morning. I think I tried something similar by checking if it was equal to None but no luck.